# Codeigniter Query Builder - Need to check if entry exists in multiple columns

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

We have a table with multiple attributes, such as:

TABLE_ATTRIBUTES
ID,     Color, Size, Weight
111,  Red,    XL       null
112,  null,    SM      10

I want to build a method inside my model, that returns the row ID, by checking all the columns for any attributes.  For example, if I want to pass 'green', 'SM', '9'.

What's the best way to build this Codeigniter DB Query?

I have something like this, but it's not working:

```
$this->db->select('id');
->or_where($color === NULL ? 'color IS NOT NULL' : 'color =', $color)
->or_where($size === NULL ? 'size IS NOT NULL' : 'size =', $size)
->or_where($weight === NULL ? 'weight IS NOT NULL' : 'weight =', $weight_10)
$row = $this->db->get('product')->row();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first `or_where` should just be `where` according to the documentation so you probably want to alter it slightly:

```
$this->db->select('id');
->where($color === NULL ? 'color IS NOT NULL' : 'color =', $color)
->or_where($size === NULL ? 'size IS NOT NULL' : 'size =', $size)
->or_where($weight === NULL ? 'weight IS NOT NULL' : 'weight =', $weight_10)
$row = $this->db->get('product')->row();
```

See this doc about `$this->db->or_where()` for their example:
https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html